# Hide subsection numbering in body, but not in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

Is there an easy way to use numbering for subsections in the TOC, but to hide the subsection numbers in the document body?

I could use `\subsection*{Title}` but then the entries are gone from the TOC.

Comment: Does it make sense? I mean, what's the purpose of a number in the TOC when the number doesn't really exist?

Comment: The TOC looks nicer with the numbers, the hierarchy is clearer. But in the body itself, it can be distracting when there are many, but short subsections.

Comment: @DaniloBargen You run the risk of confusing your reader, though. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a good reason to do that, here's how you can do.

Put, just after each unnumbered subsection, the lines

```
\stepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}<name>}
```

where `<name>` is the name of the subsection.

Note that I've used `\stepcounter` instead of `\refstepcounter` voluntarily, hoping you don't have to reference these subsections...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Testing subsections}

\subsection*{First unnumbered subsection}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}First unnumbered subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection*{Second unnumbered subsection}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}Second unnumbered subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]