# Hide section numbering in body, but not in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, unnumbered-sections

Is there an easy way to use numbering for sections in the TOC, but to hide the section numbers in the document body?

I could use \section*{Title} but then the entries are gone from the TOC. or
I could use

```
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
%\makeatother
```

But it removes numbering from all kinds of sections (sections, subsections, subsubsection...)

Comment: Perhaps you may check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148191/hide-subsection-numbering-in-body-but-not-in-toc).

Comment: Use something like [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) to modify the printing of section titles so that the number is omitted.

Comment: What a sense has such document navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy using a KOMA-Script class, e.g., `scrartcl`:

```latex
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}% Don't print section number in section titles.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: no number in section title but in ToC using scrartcl]

See the [KOMA-Script manuals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), section 3.16 for more information about `\sectionformat`, `\sectionmarkformat` etc.

Comment: I tried it but it won't compile /bf command of my title page here is my command
here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OvFBWp7EskOwDtCn7gx-kmJQ41BB2Ecj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MacTavish My answer starts with: “Very easy using a KOMA-Script class, e.g., `scrartcl`”. You are using `article`, which is not a KOMA-Script class.